# How to resize columns using grid.columns[index].setWidth(width) in ExtJS 4 when flex is applied?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2, extjs-mvc

*emphasized text*When columns' width in `panel.Grid` is set using the `width` property columns resize by `grid.columns[index].setWidth(width)` works as it should. But when columns' width is set by `flex`, this code doesn't work.

Just to make it clear: I'm trying to synchronize columns resize/move/hide/etc events on two grids.

So both grids have basically the same columns:

```
me.columns = {
        defaults: {
            renderer: tooltipRenderer
        },
        items: [
            {
                header: "product",
                dataIndex: 'product',
                groupable: false,
                flex: 1
            },                

            {
                header:'Value',
                dataIndex: 'vlue',
                align: 'right',
                renderer: Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('0,000.00'),
                summaryType: 'remote',
                summaryRenderer: Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('0,000.00'),
                groupable: false,
                flex: 1
            }
        ]
    };
```

Code from plugin to synchronize columns resize:

```
firstGrid.on('columnresize', function (ct, column, width) {
        console.log('fgrid: ' + width + ' column name: ' + column.dataIndex);
        secondGrid.columns[column.getIndex()].setWidth(width);
    }, firstGrid);

secondGrid.on('columnresize', function (ct, column, width) {
        console.log('sGrid: ' + width + ' column name: ' + column.dataIndex);
        firstGrid.columns[column.getIndex()].setWidth(width);
    }, secondGrid);
```

So, what I have now: when I resize columns with width set by `flex` in one grid corresponding column from the other doesn't change it's width, but if after resizing column in one grid I resize one from the other everything works just as it should. 
I hope this description wasn't too weird.

Comment: Have some code that we can play with? I can tell what you're asking, and have a few thoughts, but can't take the time if I have to write the start up (broken) code myself.

Comment: Sure. I'll post it in five minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not supposed to set width on something where its width is being managed by a layout. If you delete the `flex` property for the column, then `setWidth` works 
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/4b4

My example toggles the flex property so you can set width, try clicking on the page and you'll see the flexed column change width

```
// Assume you have a variable gridwhere the second column is flexed.
Ext.getBody().on('click', function() {
    var emailCol = grid.query('gridcolumn')[1];
    if (emailCol.flex) {
        delete emailCol.flex;
        emailCol.setWidth(100);
    } else {
        emailCol.flex = 1;
        grid.doLayout();
    }              
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have to save flex state, because sum of columns' width has to be constant. So it seems that I have to quit this idea of synchronizing columns resize.

Comment: @edthehead If you have to save flex state, you cannot combine width and flex in a box layout. You could try to calculate the correct flex amount so that it displays with the desired width.